# Magento2 EbizMart Mailchimp

Tags: magento2, extensions, mailchimp

Can't find original register for type QUO and ID 55061

> User name: software
>   Total Account Subscribers: 1
>   Total List Subscribers: 1
>   Ecommerce Data uploaded to MailChimp:
>   Total customers: 30525
>   Total products: 12959
>   Total orders: 0
>   Total Carts: 67
>   This MailChimp account is not connected to Magento.

Comment: can you be more specefic? when do you get this?

Comment: simple cron running

Comment: <job name="ebizmarts_ecommerce" instance="Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Cron\Ecommerce" method="execute">

Comment: any idea Amol B

Comment: Can you cross check configuration section,if there is email template by the ebiz module. If so please configure and save the settings. flush cache once done. If the issue still persists this has to do something with cronjob from server side.

Comment: one more thing my order not sync User name: software
Total Account Subscribers: 1
Total List Subscribers: 1
Ecommerce Data uploaded to MailChimp:
Total customers: 30525
Total products: 12959
Total orders: 0
Total Carts: 67
This MailChimp account is not connected to Magento.

Comment: I am not quiet clear as this doesnt give me clear idea about your current settings. few screenshots should help. below link should help you https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-or-disconnect-mailchimp-for-magento-2/ . Also make sure your API key for mailchimp is valid and active status.

Comment: acutally i have split database and quote database is on other server

Comment: I dont think this should be an issue unless the quote server response time is very high and it timesout.